# CSS - Background-image is not showing after porting from html to html5

Tags: css, html

So I have a piece of code that shows several pictures in a div that worked previously. here is the html file

```
<div>
   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container left-info"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container middle-info"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container right-info"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
   margin:0;
   background-color:white;
}

.info-wrap{
   position: relative;
   height: 50%;
   width: 33.3333%;
   overflow: hidden;
   float:left;
   background-color: black;
}

.info-wrap p{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20%;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  color: white;
  display:hidden;
}

.info-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;

   -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
   -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
   transform: scale(1,1);
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   z-index: 2;
}

.info-wrap:hover > div {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity:0.5;
}

.left-info{
  background-image: url("../image/info-1.jpg");
}

.right-info{
  background-image: url("../image/info-3.jpg");
}

.middle-info{
  background-image: url("../image/info-7.jpg");
}
```

But since I want to make my html responsive, I ported to html 5 and the background-image stop showing my picture. My folder structure is

```
-Project
   -Views
      -index.html
   -CSS
      -main.css
   -image
      -info-1.jpg
      -info-2.jpg
      -info-7.jpg
```

Can someone suggest some suggestion for this fix please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try this :

```
.info-wrap{
   /* your code ... */
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;

}
```

and add this line

```
.info-container{
   /* your code ... */
   position : relative; /* you forgot this line */ 
   z-index: 2;
}
```

and try to open your image with the url that you have writed, maybe a syntax error :/

If you have modified the image and the browser continues to display the old image then you can force the full reload with CTRL + F5

Answer (score 0):

Your `.info-wrap` element has `height: 50%;`. But its container - the `body` element  doesn't have a height definition at all. Therefore the 50% height doesn't have a reference height and results in a height of 0, so the `.info-wrap` element won't be shown at all if it doesn't have any text content.

To change this, apply `heigth: 100%` to  `body` and `html`, or give `.info-wrap` a fixed pixel-value height.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using percentage units without defining them on their parent elements. Define percentage dimensions on your parent elements as well, in this case `html`, `body` and parent `div` elements (which I added the class `.container` to avoid impacting all generic `div`s):

(Note *placehold.it* images were used as demo)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.info-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.3333%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}

.info-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}

.info-wrap:hover>div {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.left-info {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300");
}

.right-info {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300");
}

.middle-info {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info-wrap">
    <div class="info-container left-info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-wrap">
    <div class="info-container middle-info"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-wrap">
    <div class="info-container right-info"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .info-wrap is using percentages and the container "the div without class", not have dimensions, you have to add a class to this div and give dimensions to it.

like this

https://jsfiddle.net/77bu3hjz/

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

<div class="container">
   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container left-info"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container middle-info"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="info-wrap">
      <div class="info-container right-info"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```